# How to use loop register results as when condition in ansible？

Tags: ansible

I want to use a playbook to create profile for multiple users. But it always show me the error `list object has no element 2`. Here is the playbook:

```
  vars:
    users:
      - test1
      - test2

  tasks:
    - name: Check user group
      command: id -ng "{{ item }}"
      register: users_group
      changed_when: false
      loop: '{{ users | default([], true) }}'

    - name: Check user home dir
      shell: cat /etc/passwd | grep "{{ item }}" | cut -d ":" -f6
      loop: '{{ users | default([], true) }}'
      register: users_home
      changed_when: false

    - name: Touch user profile
      file:
        path: '{{ item[0].stdout }}/.profile'
        owner: '{{ item[1] }}'
        group: '{{ item[2].stdout }}'
        mode: '0644'
        state: touch
      when: item[2].rc == 0
      loop: '{{ users_home.results | zip_longest(users,users_group.results) }}'
```

I have check the loop item by using debug. The item structure has beencome to `[[{...}]]`. So the loop just has one item, the playbook doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the list of users for testing

```yaml
users: [user1, user2, user3]
```

---

Create dictionaries from the registered variables. For example, put the below declarations into the *vars*

```yaml
    stats: "{{ users_group.results|json_query('[].{rc: rc, group: stdout}') }}"
    users_stats: "{{ dict(users|zip(stats)) }}"
    homes: "{{ users_home.results|json_query('[].stdout') }}"
    users_homes: "{{ dict(users|zip(homes)) }}"
```

give

```yaml
  users_stats:
    user1: {group: user1, rc: 0}
    user2: {group: user2, rc: 0}
    user3: {group: '', rc: 1}
```

```yaml
  users_homes:
    user1: /home/user1
    user2: /home/user2
    user3: ''
```

Then, the below task does what you want

```yaml
    - name: Touch user profile
      file:
        state: touch
        path: '{{ users_homes[item] }}/.profile'
        owner: '{{ item }}'
        group: '{{ users_stats[item].group }}'
        mode: '0644'
      loop: '{{ users }}'
      when: users_stats[item].rc == 0
```

---

References

- [Ansible filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html)
- [Jinja filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters)
- [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries)
- [dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-and-selecting-data)
- [getent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html#ansible-builtin-getent-module-a-wrapper-to-the-unix-getent-utility)

---

Notes

**Example of a complete playbook for testing**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  become: true

  vars:

    users: [user1, user2, user3]

    stats: "{{ users_group.results|json_query('[].{rc: rc, group: stdout}') }}"
    users_stats: "{{ dict(users|zip(stats)) }}"
    homes: "{{ users_home.results|json_query('[].stdout') }}"
    users_homes: "{{ dict(users|zip(homes)) }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Check user group
      command: id -ng "{{ item }}"
      loop: '{{ users|default([], true) }}'
      register: users_group
      changed_when: false
      ignore_errors: true

    - debug:
        var: users_stats

    - name: Check user home dir
      shell: cat /etc/passwd | grep "{{ item }}" | cut -d ":" -f6
      loop: '{{ users | default([], true) }}'
      register: users_home
      changed_when: false

    - debug:
        var: users_homes

    - name: Touch user profile
      file:
        state: touch
        path: '{{ users_homes[item] }}/.profile'
        owner: '{{ item }}'
        group: '{{ users_stats[item].group }}'
        mode: '0644'
      loop: '{{ users }}'
      when: users_stats[item].rc == 0
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Check user group] **********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=user1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=user2)
failed: [localhost] (item=user3) => changed=false 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  cmd:
  - id
  - -ng
  - user3
  delta: '0:00:00.003991'
  end: '2022-09-03 23:19:42.953581'
  item: user3
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2022-09-03 23:19:42.949590'
  stderr: 'id: ‘user3’: no such user'
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
...ignoring

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  users_stats|to_yaml: |-
    user1: {group: user1, rc: 0}
    user2: {group: user2, rc: 0}
    user3: {group: '', rc: 1}

TASK [Check user home dir] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=user1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=user2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=user3)

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  users_homes:
    user1: /home/user1
    user2: /home/user2
    user3: ''

TASK [Touch user profile] ********************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=user1)
changed: [localhost] => (item=user2)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=user3) 

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
```

---

**The task is not idempotent**

The files will be *touched* on each run of the playbook

```yaml
TASK [Touch user profile] ********************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=user1)
changed: [localhost] => (item=user2)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=user3)
```

If you want to make this task idempotent set both parameters [*access_time* and *modification_time*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameters) to 'preserve'

```yaml
    - name: Touch user profile
      file:
        state: touch
        path: '{{ users_homes[item] }}/.profile'
        owner: '{{ item }}'
        group: '{{ users_stats[item].group }}'
        mode: '0644'
        access_time: preserve
        modification_time: preserve
      loop: '{{ users }}'
      when: users_stats[item].rc == 0
```

---

**Use module getent**

Simplify the code and use the module [*getent*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html#ansible-builtin-getent-module-a-wrapper-to-the-unix-getent-utility) instead of reading and parsing the databases on your own. For example, the below tasks create dictionaries *getent_passwd* and *getent_group* respectively

```yaml
    - getent:
        database: passwd
    - getent:
        database: group
```

Create a dictionary of *id* an *group*. Put the below declaration into the *vars*

```yaml
id_groups: "{{ dict(getent_group.values()|map(attribute=1)|list|
                    zip(getent_group.keys()|list)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  id_groups:
    '0': root
    '1': daemon
    '10': uucp
    '100': users
    ...
```

Then, the below task does what you want

```yaml
    - name: Touch user profile
      file:
        state: touch
        path: '{{ getent_passwd[item].4 }}/.profile'
        owner: '{{ item }}'
        group: '{{ id_groups[getent_passwd[item].2] }}'
        mode: '0644'
        access_time: preserve
        modification_time: preserve
      loop: '{{ users }}'
      when: item in getent_passwd
```

**Example of a complete playbook for testing**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  become: true

  vars:

    users: [user1, user2, user3]

    id_groups: "{{ dict(getent_group.values()|map(attribute=1)|list|
                        zip(getent_group.keys()|list)) }}"

  tasks:

    - getent:
        database: passwd
    - getent:
        database: group

    - debug:
        var: id_groups

    - name: Touch user profile
      file:
        state: touch
        path: '{{ getent_passwd[item].4 }}/.profile'
        owner: '{{ item }}'
        group: '{{ id_groups[getent_passwd[item].2] }}'
        mode: '0644'
        access_time: preserve
        modification_time: preserve
      loop: '{{ users }}'
      when: item in getent_passwd
```

Comment: Wow, it works like a magic. Thanks very much. Could you tell me where can I find all these functions manual?

Comment: I added some references. Most of them you can find by searching the subject, e.g. *`Ansible json_query`*.  However, the quickest way is using *`ansible-doc`*. For example, *`ansible-doc -t module getent`* gives you the description of the module *getent*. You're welcome.